# How to return N most "heavy" requests

Tags: influxdb, influxql

We have InfluxDb database with `request` measurement, it contains `url` tag and `duration` field.

I need to select top 5 slowest requests (average). 
I can write similar sql-query for sql server:

```
select top 5 url, avg_duration 
FROM (
select url, avg(duration) avg_duration
FROM @request
group by url
) T
ORDER BY T.avg_duration desc
```

How to write query like this for InfluxDb?

Comment: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/functions/#top

Comment: I need to group by, and then return aggregated top 5 rows. I don't need to get latest N rows. I know how to group by in influxDB, I know how to get top N rows. But how to aggregate, and then return top N by aggregated value - I don't understand in InfluxDb.

Comment: Linked TOP() documentation contains also information about time grouping.